# Bitcoin Native Script Language

Tags: script

I am intrigued by this Bitcoin Script Language, I want to learn how to program Bitcoin with it.

Any idea where I can, find some documentation to read/practice  with ?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script ?

Answer (score 2):

Script will not be very useful if you dont know first how bitcoin work in deep, I suggest programming bitcoin, which guide you to re build the whole bitcoin software with a whole chapter for Script

free and open source here:
https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin